# How do you add environment variables to your django project

Tags: python, django, bash, environment-variables, development-environment

I'm trying to set up my project so that it can use environment variables locally

Ive tried adding it to the end of my activate file and a list of other things. I'm trying to use this

```
from .base import *

    if os.environ['DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE'] == 'local':
        try:
            from .local import *
        except:
            pass

    if os.environ['DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE'] == 'production':
        try:
            from .production import *
        except:
            pass
```

I am a real novice and often things are explained brief and matter of factly. So a thorough explanation would really be beneficial to me in how to implement this thanks. I've NEVER done anything n Bash. Ive tried doing this

```
export KEY=VALUE
```

in the activate file, only for it not to be recognized by the system, and I had to remove it in order to use my local server

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're running it through the Django web server, you can pass environment variables the same way you would to any other command:

```
DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE="local" ./manage.py runserver
```

If you're running it through a web server like Apache, you can set environment variables through your virtual host configuration:

```
SetEnv DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE local
```

Comment: is this persistent ? or would I have to do this every time I activate the server

Comment: It won’t be persistent. You would need to add it every time you start the Django web server. If you wanted it to be persistent, then you need a way for that environment variable to be loaded into your current shell. If you type `export DJANGO_SERVER_TYPE=local` in your current shell and then start the Django web server, it will be persistent as long as your shell is open.  If you want an environment variable to be automatically loaded into your shell each time you login, then you could put this in either .profile or .bashrc in your home directory.

Answer (score 3):

I have a settings module that contains something like the following:

```
…
import os
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
…

def _require_env(name):
    """Raise an error if the environment variable isn't defined"""
    value = os.getenv(name)
    if value is None:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured('Required environment variable "{}" is not set.'.format(name))
    return value

…

SECRET_KEY = _require_env('SOMETHING_SECRET_KEY')

_db_host = os.getenv('SOMETHING_MYSQL_HOST', 'mysql')
_db_port = os.getenv('SOMETHING_MYSQL_PORT', 3306)   
_db_name = _require_env('SOMETHING_MYSQL_DATABASE')         
_db_user = _require_env('SOMETHING_MYSQL_USER')             
_db_password = _require_env('SOMETHING_MYSQL_PASSWORD')

DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
                     'NAME': _db_name,                    
                     'HOST': _db_host,                    
                     'PORT': _db_port,                    
                     'USER': _db_user,                    
                     'PASSWORD': _db_password,
    … } }
```

and so on.

`_require_env` is for environment variables that *must* be set. If those environment values are not found, Django immediately raises an `ImproperlyConfigured` error. In other cases I just use `os.getenv` with a default value.

Comment: What if you need to use an env variable in views.py? For example, I recently installed mixpanel analytics, and in order to send events to this analytics backend (e.g. if a user messaged another user), I need to call some tracking code *after* passing an API token to the mixpanel class. I've set this token as an env variable. What's the best way to import this? Should I import it to `settings.py`, and then from there to `views.py`? Or should I import it directly to views via `os.getenv('API_TOKEN')`?

Comment: @HassanBaig I think you should provide it as a setting, so that django internals don't have to reference os.getenv directly.

Comment: At this point I would not follow my own advice. Instead I'd use [python-decouple](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/). I prefer it because in addition to being able to handle required/optional/default values, the environment, .env files and ini files, it also allows a decent amount of type conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Install the environ library and add the following code to your settings file:

```
root_path = environ.Path(__file__) - 2
env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False), DJANGO_ENV=(str, 'dev')) # set default    values and casting
environ.Env.read_env(root_path('.env'))
```

Add a file called .env on the root of your project folder with variables formatted like:

```
DEBUG=on
```

Comment: Thanks for the response which settings file? local production or base. Or do you mean the __init__.py file?

Comment: It is in your project folder.

Comment: I have a settings folder in my project folder. in my settings module I have base.py, production.py, and local.py