# django settings.py won't read env variable for unit tests

Tags: python, django, variables, environment

I have database environment variables specified for my django app:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': os.getenv("POSTGRES_NAME"),
    'USER': os.getenv("POSTGRES_USER"),
    'PASSWORD': os.getenv("POSTGRES_PW"),
    'HOST': os.getenv("POSTGRES_HOST"),
    'PORT': os.getenv("POSTGRES_PORT"),
}
```

}

The variables successfully get read in when I run "python manage.py runserver", during the build on Circle CI, and also in its production environment. But I am not understanding why when I run unit tests they don't get read in.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add environment variables to your django project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473108/how-do-you-add-environment-variables-to-your-django-project)

Comment: Test your vars by doing `POSTGRES_NAME ="local" python manage.py runserver`

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, the env vars work in every environment except for when I run unit tests. This post is trying to understand why.

Comment: Tests creates its own temp database, not the existing one mentioned int the settings.py file. And letter deletes the temp database.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was that I hadn't closed my IDE in some time. I had to reboot the IDE to source the env vars from the virtual environment.